# show error info for an unbound cell

Tags: infragistics, ultrawingrid

If I add an unbound column on infragistics ultrawingrid, based on other cell values of that row, I need to show an error icon to that unbound cell.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an approach you can use in the Infragistics forums:
http://blogs.infragistics.com/forums/t/47094.aspx

Alan